# Failed scipy installation

Tags: python, scipy, failed-installation

I need to install scipy 1.2.0 for python2.7 il local on a machine running rhel fedora 6.5 where I do not have sudo permissions.

I have already installed python2.7, numpy, ATLAS and openblas.

Now when I run @python2.7 setup.py build" I get this error:

```
/home/gspirito/Python-2.7.14/scipy-1.2.0/scipy/cluster/_vq.c:8344: undefined reference to `PyInt_FromLong'
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/cluster/_vq.o: In function `__Pyx_InitCachedConstants':
/home/gspirito/Python-2.7.14/scipy-1.2.0/scipy/cluster/_vq.c:8134: undefined reference to `PyTuple_Pack'
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/cluster/_vq.o: In function `__Pyx_modinit_type_import_code':
/home/gspirito/Python-2.7.14/scipy-1.2.0/scipy/cluster/_vq.c:8395: undefined reference to `PyImport_ImportModule'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/libgfortranbegin.a(fmain.o): In function `main':
(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `MAIN__'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: Command "/usr/bin/gfortran -Wall -g -L/home/gspirito/src/zlib-1.2.8/lib -L/home/gspirito/packages/include/lzma -L/home/gspirito/src/postgresql-8.4.1/lib -L/home/gspirito/vargenius_bin/R-3.4.1/lib -L/home/gspirito/packages/lib build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/cluster/_vq.o -L/home/gspirito/Python-2.7.14/ATLAS/my_build_dir/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7 -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7 -latlas -latlas -latlas -lgfortran -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/cluster/_vq.so -Wl,--version-script=build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/link-version-scipy.cluster._vq.map" failed with exit status 1
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `yum install python-devel`

Comment: @BlackBear Hi, thank you for answering, I can't do that since I have no sudo permission on that machine

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61295/6964 perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

The error message displayed essentially says that the linker failed to link all the compiled libraries. The `exit status 1` implies that there were several errors before linking thus `ld` exits. From the [Scipy Install](https://scipy.org/install.html) page you can essentially see the list of supported python distributions.

> For many users, especially on Windows, the easiest way to begin is to
>   download one of these Python distributions, which include all the key
>   packages:
>
> Anaconda: A free distribution of Python with scientific packages.
>   Supports Linux, Windows and Mac.
>
> Enthought Canopy: The free and commercial versions include the core
>   scientific packages. Supports Linux, Windows and Mac.
>
> Python(x,y): A free distribution including scientific packages, based
>   around the Spyder IDE. Windows and Ubuntu; Py2 only.
>
> WinPython: Another free distribution including scientific packages and
>   the Spyder IDE. Windows only, but more actively maintained and
>   supports the latest Python 3 versions.
>
> Pyzo: A free distribution based on Anaconda and the IEP interactive
>   development environment. Supports Linux, Windows and Mac.